# How to make a ScrollView align to left side of frame?

Tags: swiftui, alignment

For the sake of practicing, am trying to make a Worlde type app, nothing original.

I would like to make it so that the **ScrollView**, the list of words at the top of the VStack, is aligned to the left side of the screen.  Even tried embedding it its own **VStack** with an alignment of **.leading**, but obviously to no avail.

Is there any alignment option I can use, or must I go to GeometeryReader for something like this?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var word : Word
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ScrollView{
                        if word.guessedWords.count > 0 {
                            
                            ForEach(0..<word.guessedWords.count, id: \.self) { count in
                                HStack {
                                    Text(word.guessedWords[count])
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .padding(.trailing, 10)
                                    Text("\(count)")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 75)
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                GuessedLetters()
                
                Keyboard()
                    .padding(.bottom)
                
            }
        }
        .background(.black)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
    
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .environmentObject(Word())
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment given to the `VStack` determines how multiple views inside the `VStack` are aligned to each other, when they have different widths. However, if the `VStack` only contains one subview (this being the `ScrollView`), it has no effect.

Here are three possible ways to fix:

**1. Set a frame with `maxWidth: .infinity` and `alignment: .leading` on the `ScrollView`**

```swift
ScrollView {
    // ...
}
.padding(.top, 75)
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // <- ADDED
```

This will push the contents of the `ScrollView` to the left, but the rows themselves will not be left aligned.

**2. Add a `Spacer` to the `HStack` inside the `ScrollView`**

This pushes the content to the left and the content will also be left aligned:

```swift
ScrollView {
    // ...
            HStack {
                Text(word.guessedWords[count])
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                Text("\(count)")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer() // <- ADDED
            }
     // ...
}
```

**3. Use a nested `VStack` inside the `ScrollView`**

This is where `alignment: .leading` will now be useful. You can also push it all to the left side using `maxWidth: .infinity`, as for variant 1:

```swift
ScrollView {
    if word.guessedWords.count > 0 {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(0..<word.guessedWords.count, id: \.self) { count in
                // ...
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    }
}
```